# Spring Cloud Gateway + KeyCloak Giving 404 Not Found Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

We have a microservice architecture using spring boot. Hence we have a microservic, a Spring api-gateway and a running instance of Keycloak for managing authentication and authorization.

In the configuration for the gateway we have defined

```
 security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            authorization-uri: https://baseurl/auth/realms/realmname/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            jwk-set-uri: https://baseurlauth/realms/realmname/protocol/openid-connect/certs
            token-uri: https://baseurl/auth/realms/cardbyte/protocol/openid-connect/token
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            userinfo-uri: https://baseurl/auth/realms/cardbyte/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://baseurlauth/realms/realmname/protocol/openid-connect/certs
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
```

We have also enabled the JWKS URL setting in KeyCloak and added the jwk-set-uri in the same.
But when we try to access the API via the Spring Gateway
We get the error message
HTTP Get JWKS URL  Response 404 Not Found

Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain the keys

Comment: In rhe same situation, I don't access Keycloak through the gateway (but this requires to allow the gateway for cross origin requests in Keycloak conf). I share the same Keycloak in several systems (SSO) and chose to use Gateway instances for what is specific to those system for a user experience similar to Google one: I connect to Google identity, not Gmail or Drive. Sample of such a Gateway there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the misconfiguration

```
            jwk-set-uri: https://baseurlauth/realms/realmname/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

`baseurlauth` should probably be `baseurl/auth`